# How to access the repository names in GitHub with Java?

Tags: java, github

I have an application, where I have many different repositories in the GitHub. In my application, I need to get the Name of each repository. I searched a lot in the Internet and of course in Stack Overflow to access the GitHub repos but I found no suitable solution for me.

Hopefully somebody have a good idea or has experience with it.

```
@Value("${github.githubUrl}")
String url;

public void getEach() {
    try {
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(this.url);
        request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        HttpResponse result = httpClient.execute(request);
        String json = EntityUtils.toString(result.getEntity(), "UTF-8");

        System.out.println("Json kommmt=============================  "+ json);

        JsonElement jelement = new JsonParser().parse(json);
        JsonArray jarr = jelement.getAsJsonArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < jarr.size(); i++) {
            JsonObject jo = (JsonObject) jarr.get(i);
            String fullName = jo.get("full_name").toString();
            fullName = fullName.substring(1, fullName.length()-1);
            System.out.println("fullname kommt ================  " + fullName);
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getStackTrace());
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is not much clear. Can you answer these (update your post) ? `1.` Are you the administrator of github? `2.` Do you have a list of repositories to be accessed OR you need all repos under one organization? `3.` What kind of application you have? `4.` Have you tried any method - if yes, please provide information of that try. `5.` Please list out how the repo list you are getting (is that a HTTP URL / ssh URL or just the names?

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your critics. I am not the administrator, i am just a member of the github project, where all the repositories exists. So i want to get a list of all the repositories. The application is a springboot application.

Comment: My code doesn't work so far. I can't access the github but i am sceptic if this is the right way to access the reponames.

Comment: OK, no problem. `6.` How do you access github currently? `7.` Do you need to access github through your application in the same way you access in browser (with user credentials / ssh ) please specify. I suggest to answer these in your question (update the post)

Comment: also can you update what exception/error you are getting while trying to run the program

Comment: Lemurumschlag, if any of the answers helped you, please select it as the right answer (green tick). Let's help others as well.

Answer (score 0):

I could see an existing code here.

https://github.com/hub4j/github-api/blob/9ab6d570193dc381a0cda7cc4991f471499dcf24/src/main/java/org/kohsuke/github/GHPerson.java#L70-L89

```
public PagedIterable<GHRepository> listRepositories(final int pageSize) {
    return new PagedIterable<GHRepository>() {
        public PagedIterator<GHRepository> _iterator(int pageSize) {
            return new PagedIterator<GHRepository>(root.retrieve().asIterator("/users/" + login + "/repos?per_page=" + pageSize, GHRepository[].class, pageSize)) {
                @Override
                protected void wrapUp(GHRepository[] page) {
                    for (GHRepository c : page)
                        c.wrap(root);
                }
            };
        }
    };
}
```

As per [github documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#list-organization-repositories), the list of repositories would be like this:

```
List organization repositories
Lists repositories for the specified organization.
GET /orgs/{org}/repos
```

**Note:**
Or if it's just a requirement to list the repos, try this -

```
curl "https://api.github.com/users/$GHUSER/repos?access_token=$GITHUB_API_TOKEN" | grep -w clone_url
```

Steps 1,2,3 will help you to create token as in https://crunchify.com/how-to-access-github-content-with-basic-oauth-authentication-in-java-httpclient-or-urlconnection-method/

And if really rely on java, you can try the curl in java! (you should find a way to grep)

```
URL url = new URL("https://api.github.com/users/" + GHUSER + "/repos?access_token=" + GITHUB_API_TOKEN); //pagesize too

try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), "UTF-8"))) {
    for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://github.com/hub4j/github-api, it has all you need. This is a code sample that *I assume* does what you want - fetches the list of repos within a specified organization.

```
import org.kohsuke.github.GHRepository;
import org.kohsuke.github.GitHub;
import org.kohsuke.github.PagedIterable;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import java.io.IOException;

@SpringBootApplication
public class GhScanner implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Value("${github.oauthToken}")
    private String oauthToken;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GhScanner.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        if (args.length < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Expected organization name as the 1st argument");
        }
        var githubOrganization = args[0];
        System.out.printf("Fetching repos for organization '%s':%n", githubOrganization);
        var iterator = getRepos(githubOrganization).iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            iterator.nextPage().stream()
                    .map(GHRepository::getName)
                    .forEach(System.out::println);
        }
    }

    private PagedIterable<GHRepository> getRepos(String githubOrganization) throws IOException {
        GitHub gitHub = GitHub.connectUsingOAuth(oauthToken);
        return gitHub.getOrganization(githubOrganization).listRepositories();
    }
}
```